# rbind dataframes with varying names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a situation where I need to rbind multiple dataframes based on a name, the trouble i'm having is how to define binding on these dataframes when the names differ -

For instance, the names of my dataframes are:

```
AB_0
AB_1
BCD_0
BCD_1
```

And I want to rbind AB_0 and BCD_0, and AB_1 and BCD_1 - my common factor I'm binding on is everything from the `_` and after

I know I could use strsplit, but all I'm trying to get to is something like:

```
for(i in 0:1){
    do.call("rbind", mget(sprintf("*_%d", i)))
}
```

where * is some variable string with varying # of characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
AB_0 <- data.frame(a=1, b=1)
AB_1 <- data.frame(a=2, b=2)
BCD_0 <- data.frame(a=3, b=3)
BCD_1 <- data.frame(a=4, b=4)


XX0 <- do.call("rbind", mget(ls(pattern = ".+_0")))
XX1 <- do.call("rbind", mget(ls(pattern = ".+_1")))
```

Or automate using a list:

```
XX <- list()

for (i in 0:1) {
  XX[[i+1]] <- do.call("rbind", mget(ls(pattern = paste0(".+_",i))))
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you! Do you also know where I could further definition on how syntax is formed for patterns / sprintf, i.e a place that can tell me what ".+_" means, or "%d" means etc?

Comment: You're welcome. For patterns, run `?regex`, and for the formatting see `?sprintf`